# Access top panel sub indicutors sub-menu items without mouse

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, indicator, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 12.04,

Is there any way to access network manager menu at top panel(indicators area) without mouse ? may be like we access menu of application by <kbd>Alt</kbd> - it will be very convenient.

Is there any way access other indicator's functions (sub-menu items of notification,volume,...) in top menu without mouse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Give you access to the first panel menu then you can use your <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd> keys arrow keys to get to others menus. To navigate menu items you use <kbd>down</kbd> and <kbd>up</kbd>. To select you hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.